# Computation of $\mathrm{Ext}^2_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2), \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x,y))$

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, derived-functors

I need to evaluate left derived functors of  $\mathrm{Ext}^2_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2), -)$ on $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x,y)$ but i have no idea how to evaluate zeroth functor..

I wrote kozul's resolvent $P^\bullet$ for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x,y))$ so $\mathrm{Ext}^2_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2), \mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x,y))$ is zeroth cohomology of $\mathrm{Ext}^2_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2), P^\bullet)$.

But also i can't evaluate  $\mathrm{Ext}^2_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2), \mathbb{C}[x,y])$.

Could you give me some hints?

Comment: Have you tried evaluating $\mathrm{Ext}^2_{\mathbb{C}[x,y]}(\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2), \mathbb{C}[x,y])$ by just taking a free resolution of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$?

Comment: I can't write resolution for $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ since $x^2,xy,y^2$ is not regular so Kozul does't works..

Comment: OK, but can you just try writing down a free resolution from scratch, without using Koszul?

Comment: $ \langle y^2 e_1 - x^2 e_3, (x^2+y^2)e^2-xy(e_1+e_3)\rangle \simeq R^2 \hookrightarrow R^3  \twoheadrightarrow (x^2,xy,y^2) \hookrightarrow R  $ where $R = \mathbb{C}$.
So $\mathrm{Ext}^2(R/(x^2,xy,y^2,R) = R^2/(y^2 e_1* - xy e_2*, (x^2+y^2) e_2*, -x^2e_1* - xy e_2*)$. Am i right?

Comment: oh $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y]$

Comment: @user2715119 I think you have done all the hard work, though I found an other description of the kernel of $R^3\rightarrow R$. I believe it is simply the set $\{ (yP,-xP-yQ,xQ), P,Q\in R^2\}$. So you have a complex $C^.:0->R^2->R^3->R->0$ which is a resolution of $R/(x^2,xy,y^2)$ and you need now to compute the complex $Hom(C^.,R/(x,y))$. You have $Hom(R^n,M)\simeq M^n$ by the map which send $f$ to the image of the canonical basis. You will found that all the differentials are 0 because they are $x,y$ are 0 in $R/(x,y)$. So $Ext^2(R/(x^2,xy,y^2),R/(x,y))=(R/(x,y))^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Denote $R = \mathbf{C}[x,y]$. First we find a free resolution for $R/(x^2,xy,y^2)$:

$$0 \longrightarrow R^{\oplus 2} \xrightarrow{\begin{bmatrix}
  y & 0\\
  -x & y\\
  0 & -x
\end{bmatrix}} R^{\oplus 3} \xrightarrow{\begin{bmatrix} x^2 & xy & y^2 \end{bmatrix}} R \longrightarrow 0.$$
Note that this is exact since the relations on $m_1 = x^2$, $m_2 = xy$, and $m_3 = y^2$ are generated by $f_1 = ym_1 - xm_2$, $f_2 = ym_2 - xm_3$, and $f_3 = y^2m_1 - x^2m_3$, but this last relation is generated by the first two: $f_3 = yf_1 + xf_2$.

Now applying $\operatorname{Hom}\!\left(-,R/(x,y)\right)$ gives the chain complex
$$0 \longleftarrow \left(R/(x,y)\right)^{\oplus 2} \overset{0}{\longleftarrow} \left(R/(x,y)\right)^{\oplus 3} \overset{0}{\longleftarrow} \left(R/(x,y)\right) \longleftarrow 0$$
since all the matrices are zero mod $(x,y)$. Thus,
$$\operatorname{Ext}^2_R\!\left(R/(x^2,xy,y^2),R/(x,y)\right) = \left(R/(x,y)\right)^{\oplus 2}.$$